# How to find what process is running

Tags: php, linux

I have shared host on godaddy and 3 days ago i have noticed that the resources are running out cause there is more that 20 processes are running at the same time and all the process are "/usr/bin/php". 
 
i have tried several times to  kill all the processes but they will run back after awhile.
At first i was using "php version 7" and the consumption was in the cpu, after i've change to "php version 5.6" the consumption became in the RAM 
How can i find out what script cause this problem?

```
ps -ef | grep php
2042512   270938    2967  1 10:58 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271063    2967  3 10:58 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271065    2967  1 10:58 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271111    2967  2 10:58 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271350    2967  2 10:58 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271351    2967  2 10:58 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271352    2967  2 10:58 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271353    2967  2 10:58 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   271370    2967  3 10:58 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272261    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272263    2967  3 10:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272264    2967  3 10:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272275    2967  2 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272279    2967  2 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272456    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272472    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272576    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272579    2967  3 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272852    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272853    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272854    2967  5 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272864    2967  5 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272927    2967  5 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272931    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   272933    2967  4 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   273019    2967  5 10:59 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   273860    2967  4 11:00 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   273862    2967  4 11:00 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   273863    2967  4 11:00 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/php
2042512   273881    2967  0 11:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php
2042512   273893    2967  1 11:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php
2042512   274408    2967  4 11:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/php
2042512   274420  272471  0 11:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep php
```

Answer (score -1):

as php is a script have you looked to see what child processes it's running. If you do ps -ef | grep php and look at the PID of the php then see if there's any children running the command lines of the child may contain the name of the script itself. you can do a ps -ef | grep php | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 to get rid of them all (assuming pid is the first field returned by ps -ef on your box)... hope this helps :-)

Comment: i have edited my question and added the " ps -ef | grep php" result @kusala9